# How to parse sentences, words and visemes with pyTTS

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `pyTTS` to listen some phrases.

I also need to do stuff in every sentence, word and viseme of each phrase.
Although I can listen the system reading my text, nothing happens when I try to create callback functions for these elements.

Here is my code:

```
import pyTTS


class engineTTS(object):

    def __init__(self):
        phrases = ['this is my first utterance!',
                   'now I speak something else',
                   'finally I conclude with this phrase']

        self.tts = pyTTS.Create()
        self.tts.SubscribeWord(self.OnWordSentence)

        self.tts.Speak(phrases)

    def OnWordSentence(self, event):
        # it never calls this...
        print 'This function has been called'

x = engineTTS()
```

the same for sentences and visemes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not really calling the function since it has not `()` at the end.
You should replace:

```
self.tts.SubscribeWord(self.OnWordSentence)
```

with:

```
self.tts.SubscribeWord(self.OnWordSentence())
```